# Ground losses in mains delivery network

Tags: mains, grounding, loss

It is my understanding that the mains distribution system (poles along the road, where I live) has occasional earth ground connections of the Neutral wire. Maybe every pole, or just every few poles, to shunt lightning hits to ground. Is this true?

If so, I was wondering if there is a loss due to current also flowing in the earth, parallel to the neutral wire. On one hand, adding a lossy conductor in parallel with a good one should not result in increased loss. On the other, I was taught that "electricity flows on all paths that are available", and that Alternating Current flowing down a ground rod, through an earth path and into another grounded conductor or rod, is very lossy.

Is there any additional loss in the transmission system due to the grounding of the Neutral wire in multiple places along its length?

Comment: No. The ground currents are just noise and bypass for interference, although some poorly designed power transformer steel tanks loose some power by induction of stray MMF.

Comment: @TonyStewart.EEsince'75 Noise? Different from what is flowing on the Neutral wire 20 feet overhead? I don't understand.

Comment: “Y” caps may shunt 0.25mA max per SMPS per  specs . This is noise and neglible power. N is the return of unbalanced Line currents which are grounded at secondary Y coils for safety only.

Comment: @nocomprende Try to calculate the 'additional loss', and you'll see why it's impossible.

Comment: @TonyStewart.EEsince'75 imagine a transmission line with one big lightbulb as a load. Would there be ground losses in between where the neutral wire was grounded, at various poles along the length of the transmission line? Noise is not part of it.

Comment: @LaszloValko but AC flowing in and out of earth through a rod is lossy. If there is any conduction at all through earth, there will be loss, right? The neutral wire is not a perfect conductor, so the earth will carry some current. Multiply by the size of the transmission network and it amounts to something.

Comment: No, the bulb has zero ground current worth measuring

Comment: imagine that you have a 10 meter length of wire (this represents the neutral) .... it has a certain amount of resistance  ......  now you add a thinner, higher resistance wire in parallel (representing earth) .... is the overall resistance increased of decreased?

Comment: @TonyStewart.EEsince'75 You are not reading me. Current is flowing along the Neutral wire on the poles. It is also flowing in the ground, the dirt, the 'earth' underneath the transmission line, if the Neutral wire is connected to earth at more than one point, which it is. So, there is loss in the dirt under the transmission line, yes?

Comment: @jsotola not for DC. But for AC... Maybe there is loss. Conductivity resistance at the connection between rod and wet earth, capacitive losses in earth, etc. Wet dirt is not (just) a resistor.

Comment: @James, try it with a resistor made of wet earth. A really big one. Any difference now? This is not just a DC problem. And mains electricity is not just a few amps.

Comment: If I put my cell phone next to my head, some of the power is absorbed. Why? My head is not grounded to the phone. How can it make any difference? If I put an antenna in the water, reception gets worse. Why? Pure water does not conduct (much) electricity.

Comment: It's all kind of academic.  The power grid is connected to Earth for a very good reason.  Even if grounding it _did_ lower the transmission efficiency, they still would ground it.

Comment: @nocomprende Try to calculate that additional loss. And arrive to the conclusion that the additional loss cannot be >0.

Comment: Just curious as to the relative amount of loss. I was not trying to make any changes. Did you know that ranchers in the west used to collect AC from their ungrounded fence wires and thus steal electricity from the power company? True fact. The earth is stealing the electricity from the lines too, even if it was not connected to the neutral wire. Darn those real-world issues anyway.

Comment: @LaszloValko Repeating my earlier comment: *The neutral wire is not a perfect conductor, so the earth will carry some current.* There must be some loss, by definition. "Not everything that counts can be counted."

Comment: @nocomprende, but the loss from the neutral wire is reduced, by more than the loss from the current flowing through the earth in parallel.

Comment: @ThePhoton Finally, something that actually seems to address the question! You are saying that the earth conduction is greater than the earth loss. Perhaps. I wonder if this has been documented anywhere? AC losses in wet soil are not a trivial bit of calculation.

Comment: And then there are those pinging and whining noises the high-voltage transmission lines make...

Comment: I think the pinging and whining are just from wind blowing the wires. The buzzing is an actual electrical effect.

Comment: @nocomprende It's trivial to calculate the loss in a conductor, presuming some random R resistance. You only need Ohm's law. It's also trivial to calculate that using two conductors in parallel can never have additional loss compared to a single one of them.

Comment: @LaszloValko What is the loss where a ground rod contacts the earth? In sand? Near the ocean shore? In Loamy soil? On a dry day? After a rainstorm... It is so easy to calculate. And that AC stuff, doesn't add any complexity to calculations, at all.

Comment: I used to have a room humidifier which consisted of a pair of stainless steel electrodes in a plastic basin of water. The water would slowly boil away. Why? What if... Some big ground rods were stuck in the ground (where else?) and the ground was, wet? Anything interesting happening there?

Comment: Power Factor can cause increased losses beyond what is expected just from the power dissipated by a fluorescent lamp or motor. This is what I am talking about. Are there any losses similar to power angle dependent ones in wet soil? I suspect the answer is *yes*, but we apparently will never find that out here.

Answer (score 2):

> The neutral wire is not a perfect conductor, so the earth will carry
>   some current. There must be some loss, by definition.

For a single phase supply, the neutral wire will carry the full-load current and let's say that the wire resistance between load and pole transformer is in the region of 0.01 ohms.

So, if there is 100 amps, the neutral wire losses are 100\$^2\$ x 0.01 = 100 watts.

If the neutral wire is grounded both at the load-end and at the pole-end and that earth ground is (say) 0.1 ohms, the net impedance is 0.01 || 0.1 ohms = 0.009 ohms. With 100 amps flowing the losses are 90 watts.

In other words, the grounding makes the impedance lower and losses are reduced.

[image]

As far as I'm aware there are earthing points on poles carrying transformers but it's unclear whether there are also earthing wires on poles that don't carry ancillary equipment. I can't be 100% sure but I think I've seen earth wires on plain ordinary electric poles. Maybe it's different in different countries and regions?

Comment: You can be sure that it varies a lot worldwide.

Comment: All house power entry points have a Nuetral/Ground/GroundStake which you need to consider of course. The local distribution (at least here in the US is 3 wire Delta. A pole transformer is Delta to Wye for 3 phase or 2 phase (from the Delta) to biphase and is the first point at which a neutral/Ground connection is required.

Comment: earth to earth connections over a long haul can be as higher than 100 Ohms, so earth is not a perfect conductor either and depends on water content and ionic content.

Comment: And now the same for three phase systems please ^

Comment: @PlasmaHH feel free to contribute lol

Answer (score 0):

Earth ground resistance between transmission line bonding or "earthing" or "grounding" as they say in the USA is rarely less than the Neutral resistance.

Although unbalanced line currents carried in Neutral may be offset from the next earthing connection and will result in earth currents, these may be 50% but I don't know any power distribution design engineer that would rely on Earth conductance to reduce the cost of the Neutral Wire and thus raise it's resistance more than Earth to Earth resistance between "bonding points".

Earth losses are only critical for local transient protection from lightning and have dramatically reduced protection to discharges at a distance.

> “Earthing” is a term used in Europe or other countries that employ International Electric Commission (IEC) standards. The term “earthing” in European or IEC countries is synonymous with the term “grounding” in North America.

Comment: Ground, it's not just for Earth anymore. It's funny, because in England they have the phrase "gone to ground" (when hunting). No one says "gone to earth".